# Ansi SQL type casting

Tags: sql, casting, ansi-sql

Is it allowed to cast types in ANSI SQL like in postgres for example:

```
SELECT SUM( CAST(qnty AS int) - CAST(reserve AS int) )  AS sum
...
```

*qnty* and *reserve* are character columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `CAST` expression was added in SQL-92. You can see it for example in this [draft](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).