# SQL cast target types: standardized?

Tags: sql, casting, ansi-sql

SQL function

```
cast(expression as type):
```

It is ANSI standard. Is the type standardized? what types are allowed? Are they different from database to database?

Looked at the MySQL and others. MySQL has signed/unsigned, others has INT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansi SQL type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530003/ansi-sql-type-casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAST()` is ANSI standard.  Off the top of my head, ANSI data types are things like:

- `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC`(scale, precision)
- `VARCHAR()`/`CHAR()`
- `DATE`/`TIME`/`DATETIME`/`INTERVAL`
- `DOUBLE PRECISION`/`FLOAT`
- `BIGINT`/`INT`/`SMALLINT`

MySQL changes the syntax a bit.  So, `UNSIGNED` and `SIGNED` are used instead of `INT`.  And `CHAR` is used for all the character types.  Other databases have their own modification for `CAST()`.  For instance Google BigQuery uses `string` instead of the character types.

Comment: Only the cast syntax is standard.